# Angular Material Mat-select not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use latest angular material. I am stuck at mat-select component.
Here is my html.

```
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(value)]="selectedLevel">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Options are populated properly but when i select one option then there is no select value in mat-select element, it is blank. But when i tried to inspect in browser, the required element exists when was hidden in UI

```
<span class="ng-tns-c4-1 ng-star-inserted">Steak</span>
```

What might be the missing thing here, anyone can you please help me ?

Comment: Have you copied correctly the component.ts from the example ?

Comment: @Wandrille yes i copied it properly and there is nothing special rather than foods list

Comment: @Igor I tried that also and not working

Comment: `when i select one option then there is no select value in mat-select element` <= how are you selecting this? Do you mean select in the code behind (.ts file) or interacting with the control via the browser?

Comment: @Igor it is in browser. It seems like something make it hidden but i could not figure it

Answer (score 5):

You need to read the selected value back in the component, do not try to parse the HTML looking for it. You are binding the value using `[(selectedLevel)]` so `selectedLevel` in your component has the selected value of that select.

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgr1ep)

---

**select-overview-example.html**

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" name="foods" [(value)]="selectedFood">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<p>Selected food = {{selectedFood}}</p>

<h4>Basic mat-select with ngModel</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" name="foods2" [(ngModel)]="selectedFoodModel">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>Selected food = {{selectedFoodModel}}</p>
```

**component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  selectedFood: string;
  selectedFoodModel: string;
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.selectedFood = this.foods[1].value;
    this.selectedFoodModel = this.foods[1].value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that when you created your foods list, the key does not match what you are using in the view... for example, if you created the food list like below, it will replicate the issue you are describing.

```
foods = [
    {id: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {id: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {id: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
```

The reason is, your view expects `food.value` but there is no `food.value` key, only the `food.id` key.

Double check the way you created your food array, and make sure the keys match what you are using in the view.